# Code Building Error in Eclipse CDT for Player/Stage simulator

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt, simulator, player-stage

I am using Player/Stage for my thesis work. But, I am getting **undefined reference** error messages while I want to build this code in Eclipse CDT-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <playerc++.h>
#include <playerclient.h>
#include <clientproxy.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
PlayerClient robot("localhost",6665);
return 0;
}
```

The error message is:

```
08:40:02 **** Build of configuration Debug for project firstTest ****
make all
Building file: ../src/firstTest.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/local/include/player-3.0/libplayerc++ -include/usr/local/include/player-3.0/libplayerc++/playerc++.h -include/usr/local/include/player-3.0/libplayerc++/clientproxy.h -include/usr/local/include/player-3.0/libplayerc++/playerc++config.h -include/usr/local/include/player-3.0/libplayerc++/playerclient.h -include/usr/local/include/player-3.0/libplayerc++/playererror.h -include/usr/local/include/player-3.0/libplayerc++/utility.h -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 `pkg-config --cflags playerc++` -MMD -MP -MF"src/firstTest.d" -MT"src/firstTest.d" -o "src/firstTest.o" "../src/firstTest.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/firstTest.cpp
Building target: firstTest
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ `pkg-config --libs playerc++` -o "firstTest" ./src/firstTest.o
./src/firstTest.o: In function `main':
/home/nafees/workspace/firstTest/Debug/../src/firstTest.cpp:19: undefined reference to `PlayerCc::PlayerClient::PlayerClient(std::string, unsigned int, int)'
/home/nafees/workspace/firstTest/Debug/../src/firstTest.cpp:19: undefined reference to `PlayerCc::PlayerClient::~PlayerClient()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [firstTest] Error 1

08:40:02 Build Finished (took 514ms)
```

I have followed this nice tutorial posted by Jenny- http://yorkroboticist.blogspot.com/2010/03/playerstage-on-eclipse.html

In this link you will get the snapshots of my Eclipse Project Properties:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9hcmditufu0lt6v/AAChqD1-FMM9FhvTWpuOGMQ-a?dl=0

I have tried a lot of ways to remove this error. but, all in vein. Please help me to continue my thesis.

With thanks 
Nafees

Comment: Afraid I don't know the answer and this lib in particular, but one thing that might help is that this is compiling correctly. So there's nothing wrong with your include paths or anything like that. The compiler can see the definition for `PlayerClient` but the linker can't find the implementation for it. So all of your debugging here should revolve around linker settings, and also possibly looking at this Player/Stage documentation for things like preprocessor flags you might need to define based on how you are building/linking to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the "undefined reference" problem.....

If anyone wants to use eclipse CDT for stage/player simulation, please follow these steps. I am assuming that you have installed the Player/Stage properly.

1. Go to Project **Properties**.
2. Expand **C/C++ Build**.
3. Click on **Settings**.
4. **If you want to build C++ code**, follow these steps-

   - Under **GCC C++ Compiler**, click on **Miscellaneous** tab.
   - There is a box named **"Other flags"**. Paste this line(with ` symbols) on the box-

   **`pkg-config --cflags playerc++`**

   - caution: Never edit the existing lines in the box. Just paste the above line beside the existing line with an space. And keep in mind ' and ` is not same.
   - Then, go to **includes/directories**(name may vary according to eclipse version) tab. There is an **"include paths(-I)"** box. click on **add** button and navigate to- **Computer > usr > local > include > Player- x.x** and press ok.
5. **If you want to build C code**, Skip number 4 instruction and follow these steps instead-

   - Under **GCC C Compiler**, click on **Miscellaneous**.
   - There is a box named **"Other flags"**. Paste this line (with ` symbol) on the box-

   **`pkg-config --cflags playerc`**

   - caution: Never edit the existing lines in the box. Just paste the above line beside the existing one it with an space. And keep in mind ' and ` is not same
   - Go to **includes/directories**(names may vary according to eclipse version) tab. There is an *"include paths(-I)"* box. click on **add** button and navigate to- **Computer > usr > local > include > Player- x.x** and press ok.
6. Now, The most important steps come here. Under **GCC C++ Linker**, click on **Miscellaneous** tab. There is a box named **"Linker flags"**.

   - **if you are using C++, paste** the following line-

   **`pkg-config --libs playerc++`**

   - **If you are using C, paste** the following line instead of the above-

   **`pkg-config --libs playerc`**

   - Now, go to **Libraries** tab and there you will see **"Libraries (-l)"** box. Press **add** button and
   - **If you are using C++, paste** the line-

   **playerc++**

   - **If you are using C, paste** the following line instead of the above-

   **playerc**

   - Finally, there is a box named **"Library search path (-L)"** beneath. Click on **add** button and navigate to- **Computer > usr > local > lib** and click ok.

Thats it....... Now try to compile and build an example code. :) :) :)